# Importing a class within an npm module in meteor

Tags: meteor, npm, meteor-blaze

I am trying to import a class **AllHtmlEntities** from the npm module [html-entities](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities) But I'm not able to do it. I tried this `import Entites from 'html-entities'` but it's giving me an error. I tried doing this `var Entities = require('html-entities').AllHtmlEntities;` and it **worked**, but the meteorjs docs suggests using **import** instead of require.

Does anyone know what the `import` equivalent of `var Entities = require('html-entities').AllHtmlEntities;` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import {AllHtmlEntities as Entites} from 'html-entities';
```

Comment: btw if you are interested in learning what the `import` deal is, you can google ES6 modules. It's basically ES6 equivalent of require

Comment: @k.chao.0424 ohkay. Got it. Thanks.